# How to stop EAS local build from launching a metro build a new terminal window

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

When doing a local EAS build to deploy to my device or production EAS always starts a new terminal window with a "metro start" or "expo start". It is annoying because metro is not used in my preview or production builds. Furthermore it starts a new terminal command like when I am using iTerm2 and even starting the EAS build from iTerm2.

How do I stop this step of the EAS local build?

> eas build --local --clear-cache --profile production --platform ios --non-interactive
> eas build --local --clear-cache --profile preview --platform ios --non-interactive

### eas.json:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.9.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {}
    },
    "production": {
      "distribution": "store",
      "ios": {
        "autoIncrement": "version"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `which eas` ?

Comment: the build runs but it launches a new terminal window in the background which runs metro server.

Comment: That didn't answer my question.

Comment: sorry you are right. I don't install eas globally. so I get ./node_modules/.bin/eas which is version eas-cli/5.9.1 darwin-arm64 node-v18.17.1

Comment: So what command are you running from the command line?  I am wondering if there is some extra layer of indirection that is invoking an additional shell or something?  It is weird behaviour to me.

Comment: i use "eas build" from command line. it executes the build in the shell that I am in and near the end of the build it launches another terminal window in which it runs metro server with the QR code. Then the build finishes normally. but now I have a metro server running on another shell window.

Comment: How do you have `eas` in your PATH then?  Again, it is why I would like to know what `which eas` returns.

Comment: I found a partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution:

To force build command to use iterm2 as terminal you need to associate .command extension to run with iterm2.

this is the command that gets launched during the build process.

> node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command

I still need to figure out how to turn it off compeletely.

Comment: Hmmm...I've never run into this.  I use iTerm2.  What do you mean by "force build command to use iTerm2"?  What else would it use?